# APC - PHP 5.2.17 - Windows - IIS

Tags: php, iis, apc

I am trying to get APC up & running but there are to many versions out there - and to many open questions. My configuration is as follows:

PHP 5.2.17 windows installer
Server 2003
IIS

I also seen some topics that the cant be uninstalled?

Questions,

1. What file should i download from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ ?
2. Is it possible to get APC to work with this config?

Regards, Joakim

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can install APC with pecl, which should come with PHP.

So find the pecl executable and run from command: pecl install apc.

Then make sure it places the .so in the right directory.

Note that I'm a linux user, not sure if this works exactly the same way on Windows.

Edit:

First result on google: http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/install_and_configure_apc_on_iis

Comment: Sorry but there are no windows binaries for pecl?

Comment: Ah bummer, well your downloads link still seems to have the extension you need, just download php_apc-3.1.5-5.2-nts-vc6-x86.zip or php_apc-3.1.5-5.2-vc6-x86.zip depending on whether you have a thread safe or non thread safe version of php installed. If you dont know just try them both, it will simply fail to start if you use the wrong one.